# Specifying which of two network connections Firefox should use

Tags: windows, firefox, proxy

### the environment

- Win 7
- non-admin (i.e., can not change routes)
- able to change proxy settings on FF only
- LAN1 = corporate network with webfilter
- LAN2 = wireless card connected to my Galaxy S3

### the goal

Switch automatically from LAN1 to LAN2 based on domain (ex: facebook.com).

### what i have tried so far

I started by just letting Windows try to figure that if facebook.com cant be reached from LAN1, it should try LAN2. That won't work though. Disconnecting LAN1 cable forces everything through LAN2, of course. I then tried changing routes manually, but I'm not an admin, so scratch that. This means ForceBindIP won't work either.

I installed FoxyProxy on FF15, created rules for facebook.com and tried bypassing the proxy and direct connection. Still, I can't route through LAN2.

Next, I searched the net for a proxy server which allowed me to just run it (no install) and bind the LAN2 IP to it, but I have found none which met the requirements.

### now what?

I'm almost there. I am playing with AnalogX Proxy server, but the "bind ip" feature is not exactly what I'm looking for. What it does is allowing connections only from the selected network, but I want to route to the specified IP. Anyway, my proxy server is refusing connections.

If anyone has some advice on how get my proxy to work and/or on any other workaround, I'd appreciate that.

---

**EDIT**

I have found a solution, and discovered that any application can bind itself to a specific interface.

It's up to the programmer to implement it.

source here: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=11162405#p11162405

---

I will post my answer tomorrow, but will *not* mark it as the right one, since i really want alternatives.

Comment: Interesting question. Firefox could easily support this, but apparently have not decided to do so. Perhaps there are any add-ons that implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly what i wanted, but got it to work.
And it's actually very simple.

1. install a proxy service (socks/http) on your cell phone
2. turn on wi-fi hotspot (use the phone as an access point)
3. install a proxy switcher extension on firefox (i used foxyproxy)
4. configure it with your phone IP address
5. set rules for which sites you want to route through the wireless connection

What i really want is a proxy server on the local machine, not on my phone, but it worked.

Comment: On step 1, what proxy server did you install on your phone?

Comment: @Shayan [Every Proxy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gorillasoftware.everyproxy) works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Dpending on how many sites you want to route through which network, set up a proxy server on your machine that is configured to use your mobile only (LAN2), and then configure FF to ignore the proxy for *other* domains?

I certainly got the reverse to work for me, when I could use the company proxy for internal destinations (eg *.company.domain) and access my webmail via my moble (using "ignore for webmail.myhost.domain").

Comment: since i'm not an admin, i can't install a proxy server. i've tried 4 non-install proxy servers, but none of them allowed me to specify where to route the traffic.

Comment: Does your company provide a proxy for corporate traffic? If so you specify the "private" sites not to use the proxy for...?

Comment: (bad editing, continue the previous comment here): .. not to use the corporate proxy. I am intrigued to know how you can install the mobile device as a modem if you don't have admin privileges...

Comment: i didnt have to install anything. i have a spare wireless card (from an old project) already installed. lucky me.